# Pop last char in a string

Tags: php

I have this string: `13.23E`. What I need is to cut the letter `E` (or any last letter) to obtain two vars, one with the number, on with the letter.

Example:

```
$var = "12345E";
print_r(removeLastLetter($var));

// OUTPUT
array(
  [0] => "12345",
  [1] => "E"
)
```

Any help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function removeLastLetter($string) 
{
    $part1 = substr($string, 0, -1); // get chars upto last
    $part2 = substr($string, -1); // get last char

    return array($part1, $part2);
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 12345
    [1] => E
)
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/55734)

Answer (score 1):

check this :

```
$tmp[0]=substr($var, 0, -1);
$tmp[1]=substr($var,-1);

print_r($tmp);
```

Enjoy ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [substr()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

```
$var = "12345E";

$letter = substr ($var, -1);
$number = substr ($var, 0, -1);

print "Letter is {$letter} and number is {$number}\n";

// Output:
// Letter is E and number is 12345
```

Answer (score 1):

If this were an array rather than a string you would use [array_pop](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php), So I would create a function called `string_pop()` and add it to my list of helpers.

It would mimic [array_pop](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) function but for string.

[array_pop](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) works like this

```
function array_pop(array &$array){

    $last_value = end($array); 
    $last_key = key($array);
    unset($array[$last_key]);
    reset($array);
    return $last_value;
}
```

So  `string_pop` would look like this

```
function string_pop(&$str){
    $last_char = substr($str, -1);
    $str = substr($str, 0, -1);
    return $last_char;
}
```

All you have to do now is put the returned value and the original variable in an array or create a function to do this for you `string_pop_array()`.

```
function string_pop_array($str) {
    $last_char = string_pop($str);
    return array($str, $last_char);
}


$var = '12345E';
print_r(string_pop_array($var);   

Array
(
    [0] => 12345
    [1] => E
)
```

Using `string_pop()` will alter the variable passed to it (`$str`), this is because it is [passed by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) , but by calling the `string_pop_array()` function the original string (`$var`) wont be effected, only the `$str` variable within the functions scope will change.

Just to tie up loose ends here's the equivalent function for an array.

```
function array_pop_array($arr) {
    $last_element = array_pop($arr);
    return array($arr, $last_element);
}


$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,'E');
print_r(array_pop_array($arr);    

Array (
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => 1 
        [1] => 2 
        [2] => 3 
        [3] => 4 
        [4] => 5  
    )
    [1] => E 
)
```

and the string equivalent to [array_shift](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php)

```
function string_shift(&$str){
    $first_char = substr($str, 0, 1);
    $str = substr($str, 1);
    return $first_char;
}
```

[DEMO](http://3v4l.org/kUMBQ)

Answer (score 0):

```
$source = "12345E";

print_r(array(substr($source, 0, strlen($source) -1), $source[strlen($source) -1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function:

```
 function removeLastLetter($var) {
       $ret = array();
       // remove the last character
       $ret[] = substr($var, 0, -1);
       // get the last character
       $ret[] = $var[strlen($var)-1]
       return $ret;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

not a serious answer, just a funny -and very nasty, you've been warned!- way of solving this

```
$var = '10.25E';
$number = (float)$var;
$letter = substr($var, strlen($number));
```